# Custom Delete Confirmation popup on Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid where I need to customize the delete confirmation message box based on data in row being deleted.  I have a customized general message as part of Grid configuration as below.

```
 editable: {
     confirmation: "Are you sure that you want to delete this record?",
     mode: "popup",
     template: kendo.template($("#popup-editor").html())
}
```

I was looked at using the remove event handler, but that fires after the row has been deleted.

Comment: Better solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570188/how-to-change-the-text-on-kendo-ui-grid-destroy-or-delete-command-action

Comment: Better solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570188/how-to-change-the-text-on-kendo-ui-grid-destroy-or-delete-command-action

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28518079/1849455

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kendo UI grid and custom popup delete confirmation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514845/kendo-ui-grid-and-custom-popup-delete-confirmation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing you will need to do this manually. Simply add a custom button to the grid, that calls your code to delete the item.

Kendo Grid Custom command http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/custom-command.html

Sample jsbin http://jsbin.com/OZeLuXA/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Kendo has a demo on that you can try. But this is probably the latest version so it may not work well with the older versions.

Please check "Customize the delete confirmation dialog of Kendo UI Grid" on their official website, [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/how-to/Editing/custom-delete-confirmation-dialog).

For older versions you can check "Using a Kendo UI Window as a confirmation prompt in a Grid" in Telerik Forum [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/using-a-kendo-ui-window-as-a-confirmation-prompt-in-a-grid).

Answer (score 0):

HTML code

```
<div>
      <div id="div_alert_window"></div>
      <div class="dialog button">
             click on dialog: <input type="button" value="click me!" id="btnClickMe" />
      </div>
</div>
```

Js code

```
   $(function () {
       $("#btnClickMe").click(function () {
           // This is for [Warning / Information / Confirm / Error] dialog box.
           confirmDialogMSG("Error", 
                                "Inflow encountered some internal error.", 
                                "Error",  ["OK"],  null);
       });
   });
```