# Kendo UI grid and custom popup delete confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I've got a kendoui grid and I'm using it inside a metronic template... I wish to change the delete confirmation popup (not the text) with a colored better one .

I'm using MVC Kendo helpers to create the grid and as far as I've seen there's no piece of code where intercept the popup message (ex. http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/templates/admin/ui_confirmations.html Event Handling)

anyone has success with it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delete confirmation popup is a build-in browser alert box

```
<script>
       alert("Hello! I am an alert box !");
</script>
```

so u need a custom grid command with custom kendo window

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HRcKK/1102/)

Comment: tarek I've created the column as you suggested but I've got some problem with the style. ..I'm working on this, by the way thanks for your help!