# How to create a custom confirm dialog in Kendo htmlhelper or Jquery

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I'd like to create a custom confirm dialog containing Kendo DropDownLists and yes no buttons. It is done either in Kendo HtmlHelper like Kendo window or Jquery. The code should be like

```
reply = confirm("...");

if (reply == false)
{
    ...
}
else
    ...
```

When dialog is open, program should stay where dialog is opened (in this case, reply=confirm("...")) and wait for yes no answer. I tried Kendo window, but the problem is that after window is open, program will execute the next code and won't stay where it is opened.

I need help on this. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514845/kenodui-grid-and-custom-popup-delete-confirmation/28518079#28518079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, you generally have two options to tackle your problem. One is to create a callback function that does what you want to do and bind it to an event (e.g. [click on a button)](http://api.jquery.com/click/), or you use a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (similar but can be more flexible and easier to read; in your case you might want to use .done() and .fail()).

I suggest reading up on the jQuery implementations of both. You could also take a look at [this](https://github.com/jsExtensions/kendoui-extended-api/blob/master/js/kendo.web.ext.js), which implements what you want ([ExtYesNoDialog](http://aspnet.wikidot.com/page:kendoui-ext-api-messagebox-dialogs)). Not sure if it works with a current version of Kendo UI though.