# Client Side Grid Row Delete

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

How could I remove a grid row just in the Client Side with a custom popup?
I tried different way to do it but confirming the delete it always calls the default confirmation popup of the grid.

Regards

Comment: show your code that returns not what you want please

Comment: I suspect you will have better luck creating a custom delete button so you have control over the confirmation popup, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786223/custom-delete-confirmation-popup-on-kendo-grid

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514845/kendo-ui-grid-and-custom-popup-delete-confirmation/28518079#28518079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example create button in each row, which trigger your function. Inside the function open custom popup and remove row direct from datasource.

Something like this:

```
onRemoveRow = function(e){
// open confirm popup

var uid = $(e.target).closest('tr').data('uid');
var dataSource = $(e.target).closest('div[data-role="grid"]').data('kendoGrid').dataSource;

dataSource.remove( dataSource.getByUid(uid) )
}
```