# How to Pass Column ID or Value to Delete confirmation in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to pass column value to the delete confirmation. Are you sure you want to delete "Column Value" ? How can I do this ?

I found the question related to my question in the below link. I want extension to this answer.

[How to change the text on Kendo UI Grid destroy or delete command action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570188/how-to-change-the-text-on-kendo-ui-grid-destroy-or-delete-command-action)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function instead of a hard coded string for the confirmation message

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid(
  {
    dataSource: dataSource,
    columns: [
      "ProductName",
      { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
      { field: "UnitsInStock", title:"Units In Stock", width: "120px" },          
      { field: "Discontinued", width: "120px" },
      { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }],
      editable: {
        mode: "inline",
        confirmation: function(e){
          return  "Are you sure that you want to delete record for " + e.ProductName + "?";
        }
      }
});
```

Example [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/EjIRA/2)